# Why i cant see keybord with searchbar?

Tags: ios

I am trying to use searchbar. I added it my project I added delegate in my .h file
 and my .m code :

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [search becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.search setFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,search.frame.size.width,search.frame.size.height)];
    search.showsCancelButton=TRUE;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{search.delegate=self;}
```

My code was so, but when I clicked bar I couldnt see the keyboard. I tried so many methods but I couldn't. Is there anybody that can help me?

Comment: Not enough information here. Can we see the code where you create the search bar?

Comment: EDITED
my .h code:   

@interface sehirRehberi : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
  IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic)UISearchBar *search;
`
all is nearly that. when [i did so][1] drop delegate and down files owner. i can see keybord but tis time i cant do what i want like put cancel button and make a cgsize etc.. 


  [1]: http://yatanadam.com/Untitled.png